# Beginner to Arrays

Tags: c

```
//This is the example  
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main() {
    int n[ SIZE ] = { 19, 3, 15, 7, 11, 9, 13, 5, 17, 1 };
    int i, j;
    printf("%s%13s%17s\n", "Element", "Value", "Histogram");//This part here is what is unlcear to me

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        printf( "%7d%13d ", i, n[ i ]);

        for ( j = 1; j <= n[ i ]; j++ )
            printf( "%c",'*' );

        printf( "\n" );  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am new to arrays and i've seen this example where it's suppoesd to create a histogram of stars and i've stumbled on that Printf and i have no clue why is it there and what are the numbers after the % do

Comment: You can search for these as 'format specification' (numbers are width) in practically any c++ reference.

Comment: You can also find the information by reading the docs for printf itself, and searching on something like "C++ printf examples" to find more code.  https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/  = `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`  the numbers here are width, or the minimum number of characters to use

Comment: Be careful with `printf` and follow the documentation very carefully. Use it even a little bit wrong and the program will break, sometimes in very unusual ways with no warning.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers are there to create spacing. If you try `printf("%s%s%s\n", "Element", "Value", "Histogram")` instead, the output becomes `ElementValueHistogram. Basically the spacing just says that the second string should take up 13 characters worth of space, even if there aren't 13 characters. The way that C formats these strings, the empty space is at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers next to `%` determine the number of characters it can take.

So for example, `printf("%s%s%s","Element","Value","Histogram")` would output **"ElementValueHistogram"**

While, `printf("%s%10s%10s","Element","Value","Histogram")` would output **"Element     Value Histogram"**

So *Value* has 5 letters, with `%10s` it would print "_____Value". Same with *Histogram* with 9 letters, with `%10s` it would print "_Histogram". Where the underscores represent the spaces.

Normally, C would print empty characters   to fill in the spaces.